# Flag declined on "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged an answer as "not an answer"

[Why isn't the animated object moving in the final video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130254/why-isnt-the-animated-object-moving-in-the-final-video/130255#130255)

That answer is OP trying to add an edit to the question, why was the flag denied?

Comment: thanks, converted to edit

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it no longer up to date.